# how to script show in below 1000px

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script but used in same page. like two times. i got error while working when i working on desktop it's work but when i check on below 1000px then it's get error like:- Duplicate Embedded Players Detected.

I think it's worked when i open desktop then show desktop script and when i open mobile then desktop not show mobile script show. please help me how to do that. :-

this is the script i used:-

```
    <script type="text/javascript" id="vidyard_embed_code_kjashdwejkhsdsheh class="mobile" src="//play.vidyard.com/dskakdehjkwhewhdhshd.js?v=3.1.1&type=lightbox"></script>
```

I used for this but it's show syntax error:-

```
   <script>
                if (jQuery(window).width() < 1000) {
 <script type="text/javascript" id="vidyard_embed_code_kjashdwejkhsdsheh class="mobile" src="//play.vidyard.com/dskakdehjkwhewhdhshd.js?v=3.1.1&type=lightbox"></script> 


     }
                  </script>
```

Please tell me how to fix that issue. Thanks alot

Comment: It is a syntax error. You can't just write a `<script>` tag in JavaScript. You'd need to inject the script using `document.createElement('script')`

Comment: will you please write in answer what you said

Answer (score 0):

```
if (jQuery(window).width() < 1000) {
  <script type="text/javascript" ...snip...></script> 
}
```

This code is Javascript, so you need to construct a script element in Javascript and append it to the document manually.

```
var headElem   = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var scriptElem = document.createElement("script");
scriptElem.type = "text/javascript";

if (jQuery(window).width() < 1000) {
   scriptElem.src = "play.vidyard.com/dskakdehjkwhewhdhshd.js?v=3.1.1&type=lightbox";
   scriptElem.class = "mobile";
}
else {
   scriptElem.src = "desktop.vidyard.com/.......js";
   scriptElem.class = "desktop";
}

headElem.appendChild(scriptElem);
```

Comment: it's show Uncaught ReferenceError: head is not defined :(

Comment: Code is fixed, should have been headElem.appendChild

Comment: Please wait i am checking will you please tell me that same script work on desktop and mobile now right ??

Comment: Can you maybe explain what you're trying to achieve? You only want to show the player when the window is smaller than 1000 px? Or do you want to show different players depending on screen size?